# How let a Countdown run in R

Tags: r

I did manage to create a Countdown with this Code:

```
library(lubridate)

check <- ymd_hms(Sys.time())
stop <- ymd_hms(Sys.time()) + 5

while (check != stop) {
  check <- ymd_hms(Sys.time())
}

print("now")
```

Now, I'm wondering whether there is some way to accomplish the same thing ("now" being printed after 5 Seconds), that is better / more elegant / faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Sys.sleep(5)`?

Comment: Just so you know, you can also get more fancy with it - for example you could show a progress bar, timer counting down, etc.